# WPF Component in Windows Application

Tags: wpf, windows, textbox

i have created one component in WPF. its working fine with WPF but when i tried to use it in windows application i am getting one issue.

i have one textbox in that control so in when the control hosted in windows applicaion and i try to type something in that textbox its not working.

i tried to put some messageboxes in "KeyPreview", "KeyDown" and "Textxchanged" events any of these events have not been fired.

so is there any limitation for WPF usercontrols usage in windows application??

one more thing i have used Dispatcher timer in the usercontrol.

Comment: Are you using the WPF host control for winforms (ElementHost)?

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN walkthrough shows how to use a WPF user control in Windows Forms. It may help you in your query.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745781.aspx